# How to plot a Start and Stop point while drawing a line in CartoDB?

Tags: geojson, carto

My visualization plots a bunch of lines on a map using CartoDB using a Start coordinate and a Stop coordinate.

My data contains geojson formatted coordinates  (for each row) I want to show a "Start" and a "Stop" illustrating the start point and the end point.

```
{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-73.978,40.762],[-73.991,40.75]]]}
```

where the first coordinate is a start and the next a stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the two points by using:

```
SELECT
    ST_geomfromtext(ST_AsText((line.a).geom))

FROM ( SELECT
    ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(the_geom)) as a
    from table_name) as line
```